# Codeigniter, get variable from segment-based URL with querystrings

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, url-rewriting, codeigniter-url

i've removed the index.php from my url but now i need to get some variable from the url , the CI solution is update the config.php

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = "PATH_INFO";
$config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;
```

this work perfectly when i use the index.php in the url , but i need it without index.php

this is my httacess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA
```

any solution ? , thx

Comment: have you tried `$var = $this->uri->segment(3)` where 3 is the segment you want?

Comment: yep but the problem that the url come form the facebook sdk ,exemple :http://mydomaine.com/fb/index/?perms=user_status%2Cpublish_stream%...etc  if i remove the "?" it work with uri->segment ... . but for now it show 404 screen , i think it's bad idea to create a fb APP with CI :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem in CI, so I wrote this function to get the query strings from the $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] variable and extract them.

```
function extract_querystrings() {
    $uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $uri = explode('?',$uri);
    if (count($uri)>1) {
        foreach($uri AS $ur) {
            $ur = explode('&',$ur);
            foreach($ur AS $u) {
                $u = explode('=',$u);
                if ($u[0]=='/') continue;
                $this->query_strings[$u[0]] = $this->input->xss_clean($u[1]);
            }
        }
    }
    //echo '<pre>',print_r($this->query_strings,true),'</pre>';
}
```

This function is called at my custom main controller's __construct().

You can modify the following line from

```
$this->query_strings[$u[0]] = $this->input->xss_clean($u[1]);
```

To

```
$_GET[$u[0]] = $this->input->xss_clean($u[1]);
```

And see if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at Elliot Haughin's Facebook library for CodeIgniter? It might provide some insights into using CI with Facebook.

http://www.haughin.com/code/facebook/